# regex to extract words

Tags: php, regex

My goal is to extract the username that comes after `/photos/` from `$file`:

```
$file = '/photos/plant_a/sort,"1,528","1,278",00:10:21,"1,263"
     /photos/forest-b/nosort,"1,528","1,278",00:10:21,"1,263"
     /photos/soil_c1/,"1,528","1,278",00:10:21,"1,263"
     /photos/jungle_c2,"1,528","1,278",00:10:21,"1,263"';

preg_match_all('~/photos/(.+?)/~', $file, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

This outputs only `plant_a`, `forest-b` and `soil_c1` but not `jungle_c2`.

These are usernames and can contain `_`,`-` and numbers. Once comma appears, it mean that's the end of the URL.

How can `juncle_c2` also be extracted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works I think

`~/photos/([^/]+)~`

Edit (since the comment about line breaks): `~/photos/([^/\r\n]+)~`

Second edit (since the next comment): `~/photos/([^/,]+?)[/,]~`

Comment: This works only because there is no other path after the one that doesn't end with a slash. If you add an other path after, `[^/]+` with match the LF and leading spaces before the next path.

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the answer to prevent matching the line breaks

Comment: This did work. Thanks. But I tested it with other data sets, please check my updated question.